# Errore whille upgrade nginx

Tags: server, apt, package-management, dpkg, nginx

I have a server with ubuntu, on this server I installed gitlab, for necessity I have to update nginx to run other applications! But when I do apt-get upgrade, will I get this error? (I searched the internet for something to solve it, but for the moment I did not find anything)

**Error:**

```
sudo apt-get install nginx --configure
E: Command line option --configure is not understood in combination with the oth                  er options
root@ubuntudev:/home/riccardo# dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@ubuntudev:/home/riccardo#  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro                  r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
dependency: command not found
```

**Error:(try apt-get upgrade -f)**

```
apt-get upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nginx-core (1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
â nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-01-09 08:18:24 CET; 4ms ago
  Process: 16180 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 16176 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 09 08:18:21 ubuntudev nginx[16180]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 ...)
Jan 09 08:18:22 ubuntudev nginx[16180]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 ...)
Jan 09 08:18:22 ubuntudev nginx[16180]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 ...)
Jan 09 08:18:23 ubuntudev nginx[16180]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 ...)
Jan 09 08:18:23 ubuntudev nginx[16180]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 ...)
Jan 09 08:18:24 ubuntudev nginx[16180]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Jan 09 08:18:24 ubuntudev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited...=1
Jan 09 08:18:24 ubuntudev systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance we...r.
Jan 09 08:18:24 ubuntudev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 09 08:18:24 ubuntudev systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'ex...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-full (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                         unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The command is just `sudo apt-get install nginx` no --configure option.

Comment: i have same error @Panther

Comment: Post the command without the --configure option as you can not possibly have the same error ("Command line option --configure is not understood ..." will not be present without the --configure option).

Comment: i have add result with command: apt-get upgrade -f

Comment: It appears some of the output has been truncated. What happens when you run the comands suggested - See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe"